# Identifying PWM IC with marking on device M01 35 (package is SOT23-6)

Tags: pwm, identification

I am trying to do some repair on a internal DC adapter (Topow POW 3102A ver : 1.1 ) for BigBen ST01 iPod/iPhone Docking Station where I found this 6 pin ( package sot23-6) PWM IC marked M01 35. I am unable to find any of its details. So requesting if anyone could help me in finding datasheet for  the  IC or analog.

[image]

---

May be it is LD7535?

[image: additional image IC]

```
Pin  PCB  
1    GND  
2    FB  
3    ?  
4    ?  
5    Vin  
6    ?
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a [LD7535M BL](https://u.dianyuan.com/bbs/u/70/1500781224657465.pdf) from Leadtrend Technology Corporation.

The marking is in YW1/35 format (Y = year code, W = week code and the embossed font character means Pb-free package)

[image]

picture from [epstik](https://epstik.com/ua/p888538264-ld7535-kontroller-pitaniya.html)

[image]